# Multiple Instance AWS CDK python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to launch multiple instances via AWS CDK using Python.

below code will create a single instance.

```
 instance = ec2.Instance(self, "Instance",
        instance_name = "myinstance",
        instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t3a.medium"),
        machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.generic_windows({
                     'us-east-x': 'amiid',
                       }),
```

How can write in a loop? tried with forloop and while loop, failed.

Comment: "Failed" is not helpful. If you posted the error message, we would see that it's very informative - it shows that you have multiple constructs with the same logical ID in one scope. Logical ID needs to be unique per scope.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't post what error you received or an example of your loop I'll explain briefly how you might launch multiples of a single resource:

As [gshpychka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10418515/gshpychka) mentioned in reply to your question each construct you create, in your case an EC2 instance, must be uniquely identified. If you review the [instance construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Instance.html#instance), or any construct for that matter, you will notice the parameters that are required. First, is the `scope` which refers to the stack you are creating. Second, is the `id` which is the id of the construct you are creating within the stack (you can [learn more about Construct IDs in this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_construct_ids)). This id must be unique. Your code re-uses the `Instance` string as the id so when passed repeatedly in a loop this string is not unique. In order to launch multiples of an EC2 instance in python you might do something like below:

```
# define your desired instance quantity
num_instances = 5

# for each in that number range
for n in range(0, num_instances):
  # convert the number to a str so we can add to the id
  num_str = str(n)
  # use leading zeros so naming is consistent for double digit numbers
  suffix = num_str.zfill(2)
  # create the instance
  ec2.Instance(self, 'Instance{}'.format(suffix),
    instance_name = "myinstance"
    instance_type = ec2.InstanceType("t3a.medium"),
    machine_image = ec2.MachineImage.generic_windows({
                      'us-east-x': 'amiid',
                    }),
```

This should create 5 instances with and `id` like follows:

- Instance01
- Instance02
- Instance03
- etc